# How to get predicted values (independent variable) for each observation in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, statistics

I ran a regression in Matlab and got the normal results (coefficients etc.). I would like to ask, how can I now calculate the predicted values (independent variable) of this model for each observation in my dataset and then save the values directly to a file?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you ran a regression, you should have a closed form model that explains its behaviour (within a certain tolerance of error).  Can you not just substitute the observation / independent values into your model?  Can you give us more info?  What does your model look like? What does your code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have some arbitrary function that you've fitted your data to, then you can write a separate function like so:

```
function y_pred = calcy(coeffs,xvals)
%%//coeffs is a vector of the fitted coefficients, x is a vector
%%//Calculate the predicted values here using whatever model you're using and the fitted
%%//coefficients and x-values

end
```

In your main function you'll call:

```
y_pred = calcy(coeffs,xvals);
dlmwrite('file.txt',y_pred);
```

This will write the vector in comma-delimited format to your directory. You can look at documentation of dlmwrite for how to change the format to suit your needs.